# Generalized Schroedinger Equation

Tags: schroedinger-equation, field-theory

Given a Lagrangian for N particles of the form
$$L = \sum_i\frac{1}{2}m\dot{q}^2 - V(q^i) ,$$ 
what one usually does, is to diagonalize the matrix $\left.\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial q^i \partial q^j}\right|_{q_{cl}}$, where $q_{cl}$ is the point where $\left.\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial q^i}\right|_{q_{cl}}=0$.
Diagonalizing the above Hessian type matrix, means basically changing basis from the $q^i$s to $\tilde{q}^i$ with a *unitary* (if the Hessian is Hermiatian, as I will assume) transformation
$$\tilde{q}^i = U^{i}_j q^j,$$
where $U^\dagger U = 1$. The merit of doing this is that the Lagrangian boils down to a sum of harmonic oscillators (if we ignore higher order terms in the expansion of the potential).
As fas as I understand, in field theory, the above generalizes to infinite degrees of freedom, so the dictionary is : $q^i(t) \rightarrow \phi(x,t) $, namely the discrete index $i$ becomes a continuous variable $x$. In this case the diagonalization of the Hessian matrix (which, in the infinite degrees of freedom limit, becomes a Hermitian operator) involves solving a Schroedinger type equation. Solving the Schrodinger type equation we demand that the eigenfrequencies $\omega^2$ be non-negative, so that the interpretation of particles still holds.
The change of basis now is written 
$$\tilde{\phi}(k) = \int d^3x \  e^{-ikx}\phi(x),$$
where the role of the unitary matrix is now played by the eigenfunctions of the Schroedinger type equation $U^i_j \rightarrow U(k,x) = e^{ikx}$.
In this case, it is obvious that $c_k (x) \equiv e^{ikx} = c_{-k}^*(x)$. And this reminds me of the $U^\dagger U = 1$ condition.

> My question is the following: Will $c_k(x) = c_{-k}^*(x)$ always hold no  matter what the Schrodinger type equation is? It seems to me that it should, since it's related to the $U^\dagger U = 1$ condition which must always hold, since a Hermitian operator can only be diagonalized by a unitary transformation of basis.

Comment: On first thought, I think these are two different things. The c relation is because $\phi$ is real. It doesn't hold if $\phi$ is a complex scalar field, though your unitarity condition still does.

Comment: It seems to me that no matter what Schroedinger equation I solve, its eigenfunctions $\phi_k (x)$ satisfy the above condition, namely $\phi_{-k}^{*}(x) = \phi_{k}(x)$. The only loophole I see is maybe in a scattering solution, if the phase shift might ruin that condition.

Comment: Can you clarify your notation? What is $c_k$? What is $\phi_k$? What is $\bar{\phi}(k)$? By writing $k$, are you restricting to Fourier transforms or not?

Comment: Ok, Say we want to solve the  equation $\left(-\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}\right)\psi (x) = \omega^2 \psi (x)$. THEN the solution of this is indeed $e^{ikx}$. So in that sense the change of basis you have to do to diagonalize the above operator is a Fourier Transform. Namely, $\tilde{\psi}(k) = \int d^3x e^{ikx}\psi (x)$ simply reduces the operator to a product of the eigenvalues. By $c_k (x)$ in this case I denote the $e^{ikx}$, HOWEVER, if the Schroedinger type equation has a potential inside, then $c_k (x)$ will not be $e^{ikx}$. $c_k (x)$ is meant to denote the general solution.

Comment: In quantizing solitons in QFT you try to diagonalize the operator $\left(-\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} + (3\tanh^2 x - 1)\right)$. For this you find two bound states and a set of free states that aren't in general of the form $e^{ikx}$ except at infinity where even there there are factors accompanying it. This whole set of solutions in general is what I denote by $c_k (x)$. For $k=0,1$ they denote the bound solutions, and for $k=3$ and above a continuum of scattering states.

Comment: I'm still confused, though, because this is not enough information to say what $c_k(x)$ means. What is $k$? If it's chosen completely arbitrarily, we can't say anything.

Comment: For example, if the Hamiltonian is just the identity, _any_ choice of $c_k(x)$ works. I can choose $c_1(x) = \sin x$ and $c_{-1}(x) = \tanh \sqrt{x}$ or whatever. You seem to be assuming $k$ is like the Fourier space $k$, but you also say it isn't.

Comment: If you're solving the infinite square well then $kL=2n\pi$. $k$ is determined by the boundary conditions, of course, you can't diagonalize an operator without BC's. In a finite potential well, $k$ is determined by the boundary conditions through a transcendental equation, while it also assumes a continuum set of values for energies above the potential well. In a harmonic oscillator potential $k$ is an integer and so on. In other words, $k$ labels my spectrum of eigenvalues.

Comment: But how do you choose the labeling? Let's say your identity holds, but then I swap $c_2$ and $c_3$. Then it won't hold anymore.

Comment: Solving a Schrodinger equation (with Appropriate Boundary Conditions) provides you with a complete and orthonormal set of functions (Just like solving the Eigenvalue problem of a Hermitian operator provides you with a complete and orthonormal set of vectors). This means that $\int d^3x \  c_{k}^{*}(x)c_{k'}(x) = \delta^{(3)}(k-k')$ ($\delta_{kk'}$ in the case of discrete eigenvalues) and $\int d^3k \  c_{k}^{*}(x)c_{k}(x') = \delta^{(3)}(x' - x)$ ($\sum_{k}$ in case of dicrete). Can we see from here that maybe $c_{k}^{*}(x) = c_{-k}(x)$?